# Load time option log-functions for package expl3

Tags: expl3

`expl3` provides for the load-time option `log-functions`. Based on what is said in section 7 of the `expl3` document I would find this feature just as useful as I find the `check-declarations` option while developing macros. Unfortunately I have not been able to find a way to make use of, or even read, the generated list of functions, i.e. the associated .log file.

Comment: I don't see what exactly the question is here: `log-declarations` certainly works as designed (functions are written to the `.log` when created if this is active).

Comment: @JosephWright Could not open the `.log` file at first. Now that I can the question has gone away, for now. I find an enormous jumble of information, including my own macros, and it finally becomes clear how important it is to follow the guidelines on naming variables and functions.